# JSON to csv to gzip to s3 while streaming without using too much memory

Tags: json, node.js, csv, amazon-s3, stream

We need to implement a cron service in node js that follows this flow:

1. query from postgres lot's of data (about 500mb)
2. transform json data into another json
3. convert json to csv
4. gzip
5. upload to s3 with "upload" method

Obviusly, we need to implement this procedure using streams, without generating memory overhead.

we got lot's of problems:

1. we are using sequelize, an SQL orm. With it, we can't stream the queries. So we are converting our JSON returned by the query into a readable Stream
2. we can't find an elegant and clever way to implement a transform stream that transforms the json returned by the query. (for example input-> [{a:1,b:2}..] --> output ->[{a1:1,b1:2}..]
3. while logging and tryng to write to fs instead of s3 (using fs.createWriteStream), seems that the file is created at same time as the pipeline starts but the size it's about 10bytes and it became consistent only when the streaming process is finished. Furthermore, lot's of RAM is used and the streaming process seems to be useless in terms of memory usage.

How would you write this flow in node js?
I've used the following libraries during my experiments:

- json2csv-stream
- JSONStream
- oboe
- zlib
- fs
- aws-sdk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the Sequelize results are being read into memory anyway, I don't see the point of setting up a stream to transform the JSON (as opposed to directly manipulating the data that's in memory already), but say you would port the Sequelize queries to `mysql`, which does provide streaming, you could use something like this:

```
const es       = require('event-stream');
const csv      = require('fast-csv');
const gzip     = require('zlib').createGzip();
const AWS      = require('aws-sdk');
const s3Stream = require('s3-upload-stream')(new AWS.S3());

// Assume `connection` is a MySQL connection.
let sqlStream = connection.query(...).stream();

// Create the mapping/transforming stream.
let mapStream = es.map(function(data, cb) {
  ...modify `data`...
  cb(null, data);
});

// Create the CSV outputting stream.
let csvStream = csv.createWriteStream();

// Create the S3 upload stream.
let upload = s3Stream.upload(...);

// Let the processing begin.
sqlStream.pipe(mapStream).pipe(csvStream).pipe(gzip).pipe(upload);
```

If the "input stream" were emitting JSON, you can replace `sqlStream` with something like this:

```
const JSONStream = require('JSONStream');

someJSONOutputtingStream.pipe(JSONStream.parse('*'))
```

(the rest of the pipeline would remain the same)

Comment: you say that you don't see the point of setting up a stream if the data is already in memory. Maybe i am wrong but suppose this scenario: I have the result query in json format, stored in memory. Then I can transform this object directly. But if i convert the transformed JSON into CSV and then I gzip the CSV (whitout never using stream), i will use about 3X the memory used by the first json. Maybe I am wrong? Anyway, i'll test your code in two hours and I will let you know!

Comment: The idea of streaming isn't a bad one, but specifically modifying the data through a stream seems pointless (although I guess it depends on how exactly the data needs to be modified).

Comment: your code is working very good. Anyway, i need to modify data through a stream because i can't use filesystem and using memory would cost too much.

Comment: Hi i am getting error csv.createWriteStream() not define.

Comment: @ChandanSinghGadhwal https://c2fo.io/fast-csv/docs/migration-guides/v2.x-to-v3.x#formatting-changes